# How do you make Business Catalyst reroute to a separate login for each secure zone?

Tags: business-catalyst

I have a scenario where I have 2 groups of users, employees and customers.  I have a secure zone set up for each of them.  I created separate logins for each of them.  Question is, when someone tries to access one of the secured pages, it reroutes to a login page.  Same one all the time, no matter what secure zone the page was in.  Can I get BC to reroute to the right login for the secure zone that is being accessed?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** no, BC will always use that system login page.

---

**Long answer:** A key thing to remember is that there's only one login system, no matter how many Secure Zones are in a site.

Both [users who have not logged in] and [users who have logged in, but aren't a member of this secure zone] will both see the same `Error 401: Unauthorized` system page, and not any of the 'Login' pages you've created, when navigating directly to a secured page they don't have permissions for.

Also, when they do use one of the separate login forms, they will always be taken to the page you've designated, not the page they were trying to reach. By contrast, the system login page will return them directly to the page they were trying to open.

I recommend removing the separate login pages / modals / forms you have created, and relying only on the `401 Unauthorized` system page. It can be found at `/Layouts/SystemMessages/Error401-AU.html` (may have a different country code, depending on your site's settings).

---

Please also consider upgrading that system login page to recognise when a user is already logged in; by default it misleads the user into thinking they have failed to login correctly, when they have already done so. `{{ globals.user.isLoggedIn }}` in [Liquid Markup](http://docs.businesscatalyst.com/reference/Modules/Secure-zones/module_isloggedin.html#named-params) can be used to conditionally show the form or a message, and [`{module_data}`](http://docs.businesscatalyst.com/reference/Modules/General/module_data.html) can be used to detect & link to the Secure Zones that the user does have access to.

Comment: Robert is correct. Liquid really is the way to go about this. I have a site with over 15 secure zones and I use *one* landing page for all of them. Liquid controls what is shown and not shown. It really simplifies the entire process for managing multiple secure zones and logins.